# Eclipse: set org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra to include javafx in osgi classloader doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, osgi

**OSGI & JavaFX**

JavaFX is not present in the OSGI system classloader.

Thats why you can't access JavaFX classes inside OSGI bundles.

Normally you avoid this by passing the *org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra* to the osgi implementation to include JavaFX packages.

## **My Problem**

In my JavaFX & OSGI application i'm using pax runner to build osgi bundles.
JavaFX packages [gets added to the extra package property](https://github.com/Naios/WIde/blob/osgi_integration/pom.xml#L45) and inside the pax runner JavaFX runs fine.

In my eclipse install i'm using the e(fx)clipse plugin to keep eclipse silent complaining about missing javafx imports.

Now i tried to pass the *org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra* property in the eclipse launch config to debug my application in eclipse.

But eclipse doesn't accept my parameter passing and ignores the *org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra* and throws an *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError* if i pass all required javafx packages to it.

This is [my Launch config](http://pastebin.com/WX4Pw3pk).

A simple debug output *(System.out.println(System.getProperty("org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra")))* shows that the property was loaded but it seems like equinox is ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equinox skips the extclassloader you need to configure it with -Dorg.osgi.framework.bundle.parent=ext or even easier use the runtime bundles of efxclipse - look at our tutorials and ask more questions at our forum

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and help tom. I tried to add the bundle.parent=ext property but it didn't help. What i'm wondering about is that it works with pax runner [config](http://pastebin.com/HPtuYxVE) that uses equinox too but not inside eclipse. Also if i pass the config inside eclipse like pax runner does. I will open a topic in the e(fx)clipse forum.